# Clear Databound datagridview vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview that gets data from the database, it's working fine but then when i close the form and open it again it wont clear the previous content. It will output the previous selection with the new selection made.
I have tried this codes:

```
    compSpecs.modelDatagridview1.DataSource = Nothing
    compSpecs.modelDatagridview1.Rows.Clear()
    compSpecs.modelDatagridview1.Columns.Clear()
```

But it still wont clear. Maybe i'm not doing it right. Please help.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub load_model2()
    conn = New MySqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1; port=3306; username=root; password=p@ssw0rd; database= atos_db"
    Dim sda As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim bsource As New BindingSource
    compSpecs.modelDatagridview2.DataSource = Nothing
    compSpecs.modelDatagridview2.Rows.Clear()
    compSpecs.modelDatagridview2.Columns.Clear()
    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim query As String
        query = "select * from atos_db.itemdetails_tbl left join atos_db.brand_tbl on itemdetails_tbl.brand_id = brand_tbl.brand_id left join atos_db.item_tbl on brand_tbl.item_id=item_tbl.item_id where item='" & itemCombobox2.Text & "'"
        comm = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
        sda.SelectCommand = comm
        sda.Fill(dbDataset)
        bsource.DataSource = dbDataset
        compSpecs.modelDatagridview2.DataSource = bsource
        sda.Update(dbDataset)
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, that implies that you're using the same instance of the form each time.  If you create a new instance of the form each time you want to display it then there can't be anything left over from last time.

If you don't want to do that though, there's no use unbinding the grid from the data source if you're only going to rebind it again.  If the data is still in the data source then the grid will just display it again.  If you want to get rid of the data then you need to clear the data source.  The grid displays what's in the data source so clear the data source and the grid will be cleared too.

Comment: can you suggest some syntax for that?

Comment: For which option?